# Translations from "Oil" Flow Rate - Pressure drop to "Air" Flow Rate to Pressure Drop charts

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow

I keep getting check-Valve companies that have their product data sheets registered in Pressure Drop-Flow Rate for oil(Hydraulic oil) and I need it for Air.  Is there a translation between oil and air in fluid mechanics that can make this translation?

Comment: Are you telling vendors that you plan to use these in gas service? I don't think you can simply correct the liquid pressure drop by using the air density and flow velocity through something like a check valve.